# Bind input propertychange to new element in DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I have multiple input boxes (well actually their type="number"). Which get loaded into the DOM after page load and I need to bind them to input propertychange.

```
$('.edit-quantity').bind('input propertychange', function(e){
    ...
});
```

This works when the elements are rendered on page load but not on any new elements injected into the DOM.

I can't use `.keyup()` and `.on()` because it's an html5 input type number which adds these little up/down arrows that can also change the property.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you check the event keycodes & act / not act depending on those?

Comment: @heikkim: The `input` and `propertychange` events respond to changes to the input's value from any source, not just the keyboard, so are a better choice. The problem is to do with the OP's use of `bind()` rather than `on()`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
$('body').on('input propertychange', '.edit-quantity', function(e){
    ...
});
```

This seems to work well